# Sencha ExtJS 5.1.61 app build: [ERR] javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java, extjs

When I do sencha app build, I see error

```
 Sencha Cmd v5.1.3.61
[INF] Processing Build Descriptor : default
[ERR] javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
```

Search shows something wrong with jdk versions.I have jdk 1.8.0_032 and 11.0.11 installed on my Mac, though 1.8.0_032 set as default. How to fix this?

Comment: I have removed all jdk and used cmd with djk.. it helped.

Comment: jdks are necessary for me to do other JAVA related works.